# can CodeIgniter display 404 page for mistyped index.php url?

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I am using CodeIgniter on apache php, If I mistype url on controller level or method level (e.g. `http://www.example.com/index.php/mistypedcontroller/mistypedfunction`) I get the 404 page.

But if I type in `http://www.example.com/mistyped.php/controller/function`, I got a blank page. Is there a way to show the same 404 page here?

Answer (score 3):

> "can CodeIgniter display 404 page for mistyped index.php url?"

**No, it cannot.**  If you mistype `index.php`, then you are no longer within/using CodeIgniter.

Look inside this file and you'll see that `index.php` is constructing everything, and the very last line is including the CodeIgniter.php core file.

---

```
www.example.com/index.php/mistypedcontroller/mistypedfunction
```

This first one above is using `index.php`, so it's generated by CodeIgniter.

```
www.example.com/mistyped.php/controller/function
```

This second one, *since it's not using `index.php`*, has absolutely nothing to do with CodeIgniter.

> Is there a way to show the same 404 page here?

It would have to be a standalone file and configured for your particular server via Apache's `.htaccess` file using the `ErrorDocument 404` option.

**Alternatively**, if you simply follow [the documentation for removing the `index.php` from the URL](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file), your situation above could never occur; your broken URL example will cause a CodeIgniter 404 error because any/every URL (*pointing to a file that doesn't exist*) is forced into your `index.php` file.

> If your Apache server has `mod_rewrite` enabled, you can easily remove this file by using a `.htaccess` file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the “negative” method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

> In the above example, **any HTTP request** other than those for existing directories and existing files **is treated as a request for your `index.php`** file.